# What's the simplest way to serve static files using ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, static-files

I'm trying to create the simplest possible ASP.NET 5 project to serve static files, without depending on Visual Studio project templates.  However, when I request a file, I'm only receiving an empty response.  Here's my code:

project.json:

```
{
  "wwwroot": "wwwroot",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;

namespace Study.StaticFileServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, there's a "wwwroot" folder containing "downloadme.txt".

When I run `dnx web` and request the file, the response is blank.  What must I add to get this to work?

Comment: How are you requesting file in browser?

Comment: Is there anything in the file? :)

Comment: Mithun, I'm navigating to http://localhost:5000/downloadme.txt.

Victor, yes.

You can see the project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bryandrenner/study/tree/master/003staticFileServer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was hard to spot but there is an error in `project.json`. Change `wwwroot` to `webroot`

Current:

```
{
   "wwwroot": "wwwroot",
   [...]
```

Should be:

```
{
   "webroot": "wwwroot",
   [...]
```

The `webroot` points to root of an application where static files are taken from.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have done these but reiterating it back.

1. When you run "dnx web" in command line. Following output should be shown [image]
2. Use "http://localhost:5000" in any browser, initially you will see blank screen. Then look for file in wwwroot folder as shown below [image: Read file in browser]

Comment: This is what I'm doing, but the browser only displays a blank screen, not the text from the file.